# Convert Win 8 on a desktop to look and act like Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I've heard that it is possible to convert Win 8 on a PC to look and act completely like Win 7. Is this true?

Comment: This might seem a no-brainer, but the only thing that will ever look and act *completely* like Windows 7 is... well, Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is true.  I was aksed to do this for a customer not so long ago and followed [this article](http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-make-windows-8-look-like-windows-7/) to accomplish what I required.

Essentially, it involves changing a whole load of visual styles including:

- start screen disabling
- Disable metro apps and ribbons
- enabling classic start menu
- changing default programs
- enabling gadgets
  ...etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: Not quite. [Some features were removed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_8), and can't be easily restored, if at all. For example, to access some [wireless management functions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/manage-wireless-network-profiles) you have to use the command-line interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can to a certain extent, especially using third party tools such as [Stardock's Object Desktop Suite](http://www.stardock.com/products/odnt/).  But with the latest update to Windows 8 (8.1 and 8.1 Update 1), most of the Windows 7 functionality that people are complaining about is integrated into Windows 8, so there really isn't much point.  I would say, though, that if you really want Windows 7 design that much, find a copy of Windows 7 and install that instead.